# implement symfony/constraint/validation as assert in laravel/doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, doctrine-orm, laravel-5

For a new project, I am using [Laravel/Doctrine](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.1/orm/introduction).

All works well, I implement the [Auth](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.1/orm/auth) Services too.

I use symfony a lot, so I was wondering if there is a way to implement the [Symfony validations constraints](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#constraints) for doctrine in laravel, or anything else like this symfony component in Laravel.

In order to use in my doctrine entities like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Test
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Email(
     *     message = "The email '{{ value }}' is not a valid email.",
     *     checkMX = true
     * )
     */
     protected $email;
}
```

Is there a way to show me how to make this in the good practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think doctrine doesn't even "know" about symfonys Validator Constraints. It is the `DoctrineBundle` glueing symfony/validator.

So maybe you could install the symfony/validator and do the glue code yourself.

Here is the DIC config that bind the validator to doctrine:
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/orm.xml#L47

Comment: thank you for your answer, and indeed you're right: it is the DoctrineBundle glueing symfony/validator. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @mblaettermann, Can you provide additional information about how to solve problem? I added doctrine/doctrine-bundle via composer, but still have error. Or if I can solve problem without using doctrine/doctrine-bundle (it's more better for me) how can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

composer.json

```
    "symfony/validator": "^5.1",
    "laravel-doctrine/orm": "~1.5",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.11",
```

public/index.php

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, "loadClass"));
```

for correct works console doctrine tools need too add in

artisan

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
$loader = require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, "loadClass"));
```

the you can use validator for validate entity by the `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints`